Using non-polars operations on polars column
I'd like to apply trim_mean from scipy.stats to some polars column.
I tried the following, but am unsure about why the second option fails with
IndexError: tuple index out of range**

from scipy.stats import trim_mean

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9, 12, 15, 4, 6]
})

# compute regular mean
df.select(
    pl.col("x").mean().alias("mean")
)

# trim mean
df.select(
    trim_mean(pl.col("x"),0.05).alias("trim_mean")
)

What data type is a polars column in this case? Or is there some other method to compute this in polars?

For completeness, a running implementation of trim_mean using native polars expressions could look as follows.
def trim_mean_pl(expr: pl.Expr, proportiontocut: float):
    m = (proportiontocut * pl.len()).floor().cast(pl.UInt32)
    return expr.sort().slice(m, pl.len()-2*m).mean()

df.with_columns(
    trim_mean_pl(pl.col("X"), 0.05).alias("trim_mean_pl")
)


trim_mean expects an array as the first argument; it does not work with polars expressions. You can pass df["X"] instead:
import polars as pl
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

df = pl.DataFrame({"X": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9, 12, 15, 4, 6]})

print(trim_mean(df["X"], 0.05))

Output:
6.25


Based on the code here for trim_mean of 1D arrays, I implemented a custom function that calculates this in pure polars code:
import polars as pl


def polars_trim_mean(expr, proportiontocut):
    m = (proportiontocut * pl.len()).cast(pl.Int32)
    return expr.sort().slice(m, pl.len() - 2 * m).mean()


df = pl.DataFrame({"X": [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 5, 9, 12, 15, 4, 6]})
print(df.select(trim_mean=polars_trim_mean(pl.col("X"), 0.05)))

Output:
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ trim_mean │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 6.25      │
└───────────┘


I think your implementation of polars_trim_mean is missing a sort somewhere.

This pure polars example does not run for me.
InvalidOperationError: offset must be integral for slice, not dyn float

@Hericks oops, copy paste error, forgot to sort. Also I was on an old version of polars where indexing with float was not an error I believe (or floor returned an int).
